# How can I set dialog style in my custom theme?

Tags: android

I tried in many ways but I can't change the AlertDialog style from xml.

The result I would is to define an XML style for dialogs extending and overriding the default and then bind it in my theme, so all the alertDialogs will looks the same.

I tried:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/pippo</item>
</style>
<style name="pippo" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:bottomBright">@android:color/holo_orange_dark</item>
    <item name="android:bottomDark">@android:color/holo_orange_dark</item>
    <item name="android:bottomMedium">@android:color/holo_orange_dark</item>
    <item name="android:centerBright">@android:color/holo_orange_dark</item>
    <item name="android:centerDark">@android:color/holo_orange_dark</item>
    <item name="android:centerMedium">@android:color/holo_orange_dark</item>
    <item name="android:fullBright">@android:color/holo_orange_dark</item>
    <item name="android:fullDark">@android:color/holo_orange_dark</item>
    <item name="android:topBright">@android:color/holo_blue_dark</item>
    <item name="android:topDark">@android:color/holo_blue_dark</item>
</style>
```

and then I put in the manifest "AppTheme" as activity theme, but I still see normal alertdialogs.

Where I do wrong?

Comment: Post your code where you add this style in your AlertDialog.

Comment: I don't add the style by java, I want to set dialog style by overriding the default style.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this to apply the desired style:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style. pippo));
```

Comment: Yes, but it is not what I want.. I would to achieve this result using only xml.

Comment: I don't this that's possible.
However you can create a custom dialog class that extends AlertDialog and on the constructor apply the style. Then, invoke your CustomDialog instead of AlertDialog.